# filter out some items from a list and store in different arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, regex, list

i have a list which contains some string items

```
res = ["FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'KIDS' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FANTASY' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME =='Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FESTIVAL' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'New Delhi' & EVENT_GENRE == 'WORKSHOP' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'EXHIBITION' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Bangalore' & FAV_GENRE == '|DRAMA|'",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME = 'Mumbai' &  & FAV_GENRE == '|ACTION|ADVENTURE|SCI-FI|'",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Bangalore' & FAV_GENRE == '|COMEDY|'",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Bangalore' & FAV_GENRE == 'DRAMA' & FAV_LANGUAGE == 'English'",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'New Delhi' & FAV_LANGUAGE == 'Hindi' & count_EVENT_LANGUAGE >= 1"]
```

i want to iterate over all list items and store different value in different lists.Out put should like

```
FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME = ['Mumbai','Bangalore','New Delhi']
EVENT_GENRE = ['KIDS','FANTASY','FESTIVAL','WORKSHOP','EXHIBITION']
FAV_GENRE = ['|DRAMA|','|ACTION|ADVENTURE|SCI-FI|','|COMEDY|','DRAMA']
FAV_LANGUAGE = ['English','Hindi']
count_on_field = ['EVENT_GENRE','EVENT_LANGUAGE']
```

Till yet what i came up to is

```
fields = [re.split(r'[(==)(>=)]', x)[0].strip() for x in re.split('[&($#$)]', res)]
fields = [x for x in list(set(fields)) if x]
o/p:fields = ['FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME','EVENT_GENRE','FAV_GENRE','FAV_LANGUAGE','count_EVENT_GENRE','count_EVENT_LANGUAGE']
```

But not able to get the expected one.

So please suggest what i am missing and need to do.An example will be  a great help.

Comment: See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try regex as below, i used regex-list and `search` method for matching and `ast` module for formatting strings (for getting `'Hindi'` from `"'Hindi'"`) afteral i used `uniquer` function to get unique elements of list.

```
import re,ast

res = ["FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'KIDS' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FANTASY' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME =='Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FESTIVAL' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'New Delhi' & EVENT_GENRE == 'WORKSHOP' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Mumbai' & EVENT_GENRE == 'EXHIBITION' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Bangalore' & FAV_GENRE == '|DRAMA|'",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME = 'Mumbai' &  & FAV_GENRE == '|ACTION|ADVENTURE|SCI-FI|'",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Bangalore' & FAV_GENRE == '|COMEDY|'",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'Bangalore' & FAV_GENRE == 'DRAMA' & FAV_LANGUAGE == 'English'",
"FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'New Delhi' & FAV_LANGUAGE == 'Hindi' & count_EVENT_LANGUAGE >= 1"]

FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME = []
EVENT_GENRE = []
FAV_GENRE = []
FAV_LANGUAGE = []
count_on_field = []

pat =[ """FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME[\s==]+(.*?)&""","""EVENT_GENRE[\s==]+(.*?)&""","""FAV_GENRE[\s==]+(.*?)(?:\s|&|$)""","""FAV_LANGUAGE[\s==]+(.*?)(?:\s|&|$)""","""count_(\w+)"""]

def matcher(st,indx,lst):
    if re.compile(pat[indx]).search(st):
        lst.append(re.compile(pat[indx]).search(s).groups()[0].strip())
def uniquer(l):
    try:
        return map(ast.literal_eval,list(set(l)))
    except:
        return list(set(l))

for s in res:
    matcher(s,0,FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME)
    matcher(s,1,EVENT_GENRE)
    matcher(s,2,FAV_GENRE)
    matcher(s,3,FAV_LANGUAGE)
    matcher(s,4,count_on_field)

print uniquer(FAV_GENRE),uniquer(FAV_LANGUAGE),uniquer(FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME),uniquer(EVENT_GENRE),uniquer(count_on_field)
```

Output-

```
['|DRAMA|', '|COMEDY|', '|ACTION|ADVENTURE|SCI-FI|', 'DRAMA'] ['Hindi', 'English'] ['New Delhi', 'Mumbai', 'Bangalore'] ['FESTIVAL', 'WORKSHOP', 'FANTASY', 'KIDS', 'EXHIBITION'] ['EVENT_GENRE', 'EVENT_LANGUAGE']
```

See the live regex <kbd>[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mB0rK8/1)</kbd>.

Comment: can u please explain a bit, what u did(how), in a comment!!

Comment: in that pat expression,and inside two functions.I am just a starter in python so please ignore my ignorance.do help(explain).

Comment: and i am getting a different output  for FAV_GENRE = ["'|ACTION|ADVENTURE|SCI-FI|'", "'|DRAMA|'", "'|COMEDY|'"]

Comment: instead of each element in single quote,an extra double quote is enclosing the each item in list..how to get rid of that? Believe me i did not change anything just copy paste and executed that .

Comment: For those string `uniquer` function should do the work - just pass list into that `uniquer` function.

Comment: Thanks for the demo.helped a lot.