# using ast_literal_eval in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list and items are strings, but from some operation i got the list as string items are enclosed with extra "`'string' "`. How to get rid of that.

My code sample is

```
 import ast
 d = ["'WORKSHOP'", "'KIDS'", "'EXHIBITION'", "'FANTASY'", "'FESTIVAL'"]
 result = ast.literal_eval(d)
ValueError: malformed node or string: ["'WORKSHOP'", "'KIDS'", "'EXHIBITION'", "'FANTASY'", "'FESTIVAL'"]
```

I want the output as:

```
result = ['WORKSHOP', 'KIDS', 'EXHIBITION', 'FANTASY', 'FESTIVAL']
```

For integers:

```
res = [123, 345, 566, 78]
```

Comment: Does it have to be with `ast` ?

Comment: @IronFist-please suggest if you have a new way!!!will be a great help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah...you know, you're trying to use `ast.literal_eval()` on a list. So try this:

```
>>> import ast
>>> d = ["'WORKSHOP'", "'KIDS'", "'EXHIBITION'", "'FANTASY'", "'FESTIVAL'"]
>>> result = [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in d]
>>> result
['WORKSHOP', 'KIDS', 'EXHIBITION', 'FANTASY', 'FESTIVAL']
>>>
```

Or use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> import ast
>>> d = ["'WORKSHOP'", "'KIDS'", "'EXHIBITION'", "'FANTASY'", "'FESTIVAL'"]
>>> result = map(ast.literal_eval, d)
>>> result
['WORKSHOP', 'KIDS', 'EXHIBITION', 'FANTASY', 'FESTIVAL']
>>>
```

Remember on Python 3 it'll return a `map` object, to covert it to list just use `list(map(ast.literal_eval, d))`.

---

Another way to solve this is simply remove the first char and the last char in the string since they're already string objects:

```
>>> d = ["'WORKSHOP'", "'KIDS'", "'EXHIBITION'", "'FANTASY'", "'FESTIVAL'"]
>>> [i[1:-1] for i in d]
['WORKSHOP', 'KIDS', 'EXHIBITION', 'FANTASY', 'FESTIVAL']
>>> list(map(lambda x: x[1:-1], d))
['WORKSHOP', 'KIDS', 'EXHIBITION', 'FANTASY', 'FESTIVAL']
>>>
```

Comment: You can simply use `map(ast.literal_eval,d)`

Comment: @Kevin-sorry for this kind of childish question.Will be careful further.Thanks.

Comment: @Satya: No problem :)

Comment: @Kevin-need your help in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119386/filter-out-some-items-from-a-list-and-store-in-different-arrays-in-python/34119941?noredirect=1#comment56002157_34119941

Comment: Can it be dynamic.Means the list that are initialise first and then getting used, those should come dynamically(from program (filtering from that total list)) and assigned automatically after all computaion using dictionary mapping or something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97156/discussion-between-kevin-guan-and-satya).

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
>>> d = ["'WORKSHOP'", "'KIDS'", "'EXHIBITION'", "'FANTASY'", "'FESTIVAL'"]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> l = map(lambda s:s.replace('\'', ''), d)
>>> l
['WORKSHOP', 'KIDS', 'EXHIBITION', 'FANTASY', 'FESTIVAL']
```

Also, you can do it this way with [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) module:

```
>>> d = ["'WORKSHOP'", "'KIDS'", "'EXHIBITION'", "'FANTASY'", "'FESTIVAL'"]
>>> allchars =string.maketrans('','') #to make a chars list of 256, for translate method
>>> l = map(lambda s:s.translate(allchars, '\''),d)
>>> l
['WORKSHOP', 'KIDS', 'EXHIBITION', 'FANTASY', 'FESTIVAL']
```

Comment: What will happen if the string is `"'WO'RK'S'HOP'"` and OP wants save these `'` except the around pair?

Comment: And the `string` version doesn't work if you're using Python 3.x.

Comment: @KevinGuan, it will indeed remove the `'` char from `"'WO'RK'S'HOP'"` giving out: `'WORKSHOP'`

Comment: @KevinGuan...you are right...I didn't think that OP wanted only to remove `'` on the sides...Thanks for the head's up